# FIX(connect/merge) loose vertices after an edge split modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow, vertices

I'm modeling a very **high poly complex weapon**, and I've applied an *edge split modifier* on it, so now most of my vertices are *loose* and I can't manually add bevel. I'm sure there should be another way apart from manually merging every. single. vertex.

Perhaps I can reverse the effect of the modifier somehow or at least there should be a way of merging edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go into edit mode
- select everything by pressing A
- press W
- select remove doubles

Also, don't use the edge split modifier. If you want to smooth your mesh, i suggest using "auto smooth".